# php.ini to affect all sub-folders

Tags: php

I need to add a php.ini in a specific folder in my server to set `allow_url_fopen = true` for a website. The website has its root folder an plenty of sub-folders that also have many sub-folders.

If I place the php.ini in the root of the website, it seems to only affect that folder (I've run phpconfig() there and in the subfolders.

Is it possible to make it somehow that affects all the subfolders without having to palce uno php.ini per sub-folder?

Comment: You need to elaborate on your PHP setup/SAPI. For mod_php you can use `.htaccess`, for FCGI you are stuck with per-folder `php.ini` or `.user.ini` overrides.

Comment: well I'm on a 1and1 shared linux hosting with PHP5. De `.htaccess` isn't working so I guess I'm stuck with the `php.ini` per folder then

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding Mario's comment, I tried both `php.ini` and `.user.ini`.  As he said `php.ini` is not recursive, but `.user.ini` is working recursively for me.  I am also on 1and1 shared linux hosting with PHP5 as well.  I just put the `.user.ini` in my root directory.

Answer (score -1):

You could set PHP configurations options in [.htaccess](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php).

```
php_flag allow_url_fopen on
```

Comment: just tried that, I get an Internal Server Error and error 500